# Add time parser to axis in interactive scatterplot using D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am making a scatterplot using D3.js and I am unable to apply a proper time scale to the X axis. All my data is within the same year (2016), in a 3 months span.

I usually do this in a different way, and I want to learn what I am doing wrong in this one, which has a different code structure as I usually use in D3.

[Here is the code in JsBin](https://jsbin.com/tumotep/edit?html,js,output)

This is X axis code:

```
var xValue = function(d) {
return d.datadois;
 }, 
 xScale = d3.time.scale(), 
 xMap = function(d) {
return xScale(xValue(d));
}, 
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").ticks(10, ".f");
```

Wonder how can I apply the time scale properly, to render the months in my data.

Comment: I believe you need a `.domain()` and `.range()` with the appropriate arguments after your `d3.time.scale()`

Comment: Thank you, that helped, but I had to apply the `parseDate` element to the data as well `data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.datadois = parseDate(d.datadois);
    d.headlines = +d.headlines;`